# How to optmize my html for mobile web search

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm trying to get my html web page to optimize to mobile devices. I have have tried a couple of bootstraps but it doesn't seem to be showing up properly. If anyone could help and assist I would truly appreciate it!!

Here's my HTML:

```
<header <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">>
```

I expect the web page to be functional in a mobile setting.

Comment: It looks like the HTML is invalid; you can't put an element inside the angle brackets of another element.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to implement Bootstrap responsive design
In the body of the page
For more advance stuff you can use css media queries

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code; firstly, the `meta` tags should be in the document `<head>` - not the `<header>`. Secondly, you have an HTML tag within another HTML tag's brackets, which is incorrect - you should only have tag names and attributed content within HTML brackets.

A correct structure of a document is more like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>
      <header>
        <h1>I am a heading</h1>
      </header>
      <p>I am some paragraph content</p>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note how the `meta` information is separate from the document `body`, which houses the main content for the document.